# tikz: How to create such a picture with translucent 3D plates

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am trying to recreate the following picture. I tried to recreate this using Mathcha.io but I don't get the right translucent 3D look on the coloured plates. Is there a way to recreate this picture?

[image]

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: The problem is that I am not directly using tikz but MathCha.io to create tizk code. And the tikz code is very messy. I will trie to set this up in tikz directly and will post the result here as soon as I have made progress.

Comment: For fans of tikz it looks like an interesting challenge, but the impetus of some is sometimes used as a service to do it for me, so it is appreciated that the less you look for pieces of code in the site that you can lead to the desired result,because it costs some work, it is not done with a magic spell.

Comment: I already have recreated the figure with powerpoint and saved it as a pdf file but it looks horrible in comparison to tikz graphics. I am actually only looking for a simple solution which creates translucent 3D bodies from a specific perspective.

Comment: Well, Why you do not test with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), you will get the same, when you export it as PDF, since your drawing does not require calculation parameters or work with coordinates. With inkscape you can get an even better result, you will see that the tikz code for what you want will not be simple.

Comment: @JLeonV I don't like Inkscape because line thickness and typesetting are not as in the LaTeX file. And in order to create high-quality figures, you need to invest much more time in comparison to tikz (which always looks super cool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really straightforward. **UPDATE**: Simplified code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.2}
\newcommand{\TranslucentPlane}[3][]{
\draw[fill=#3!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,#2) -- (-3,3,#2) -- (3,3,#2) -- (3,-3,#2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=#3!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,#2) -- (3,3,#2) -- (3,3,{#2+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{#2+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=#3!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,#2) -- (-3,-3,#2) -- (-3,-3,{#2+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{#2+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=#3!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,{#2+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{#2+0.2}) -- (3,3,{#2+0.2}) -- 
(3,-3,{#2+0.2}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=#3!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,#2) -- (3,3,#2) -- (3,3,{#2+0.2}) -- (3,-3,{#2+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=#3!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,#2) -- (-3,-3,#2) -- (-3,-3,{#2+0.2}) --
(3,-3,{#2+0.2})
-- cycle;
}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{00}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\foreach \Z/\Col in {1/black,2/gray,3/blue,4/blue,5/darkgreen,6/darkgreen}
{
\TranslucentPlane{\Z}{\Col}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER**:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{00}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\foreach \Z in {1}
{
\draw[fill=black!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,-3,\Z) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- 
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=black!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) --
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
}
\foreach \Z in {2}
{
\draw[fill=gray!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,-3,\Z) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- 
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) --
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
}
\foreach \Z in {3,4}
{
\draw[fill=blue!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,-3,\Z) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- 
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) --
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
}

\foreach \Z in {5,6}
{
\draw[fill=green!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,-3,\Z) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.6] (-3,3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!70,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (-3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- 
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (3,3,\Z) -- (3,3,{\Z+0.2}) -- (3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
\draw[fill=green!40,opacity=0.6] (3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,\Z) -- (-3,-3,{\Z+0.2}) --
(3,-3,{\Z+0.2})
-- cycle;
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: plus 1: Wow, that was quick. I don't understand your code yet but it answers my question. Do you know of any direct command to create translucent 3D objects in tikz with a specific view?

Comment: @MrYouMath I simplified the code and created a command of that sort. If you change the angles in `\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}` and/or `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{00}{0}`, you can adjust the perspective/view. (I left the `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{00}{0}` because not all perspectives can be achieved by *only* playing with `\tdplotsetmaincoords`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort. I will try to implement this solution to my figure.